# Java Eclipse: How to clean and how to run from different directory

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration

For school, my current project structure looks something like:

```
nachos/
    proj1/
        Makefile
    proj2/
    proj3/
    package1/
    package2/
    Makefile
```

School has provided me with a Makefile, and I have setup in Eclipse a way such that the default builder simply runs make within the directory proj1. (So, it runs `cd proj1; make;`)

By default, this essentially builds the project and places the results within the directory proj1. Therefore, the structure ends up looking like:

```
nachos/
    proj1/
        nachos/
            package1/
               Main.class
            package2/
               Other compiled *.class files
        Makefile
    proj2/
    proj3/
    package1/
    package2/
    Makefile
```

Now, I'm attempting to do two things that does not seem to work:

1. First of all, I'm not sure if it's possible to configure `clean...` in Eclipse to run `make clean`.
2. Secondly, I'm not sure how to setup a run configuration such that Eclipse will first move into the `proj1` directory before running `java nachos.package1.Main`. More concisely, I want Eclipse to perform: `cd proj1; java nachos.package1.Main;`. By default, it seems to ignore whatever working directory I set in the run configurations and simply runs `java nachos.package1.Main` at the outer nachos directory. Obviously, this doesn't work since the Makefile by default compiles the result into proj1 only.

Note: No I cannot use some other build method.

Thanks!

Comment: I can't speak to your question directly, but as a comment on the situation: You have to work with what the school has provided, but their setup is inexcusably stupid. Be aware that any real-world projects should use a modern build system (Maven or Gradle), and it would be worthwhile to learn one of them for any other projects you're working on.

Comment: @chrylis For the last 7 years all my real-life projects have been built with Ant. It is still my build tool of choice. While Maven type tools are useful I have yet to find a compelling reason to switch from Ant.

Comment: @ufis Ant is an acceptable alternative, though I won't develop without the dependency-management features of Maven/Gradle. The contrast was intended with using `make` for Java builds.

Comment: I understand that Ant is a preferred alternative. However, this is a simple project, and all the Makefile is doing is running `javac` with some custom arguments to compile to a different folder. I'm really just wondering how to setup the run configuration to run `nachos.package1.Main` from inside the `proj1` directory, instead of the main outer `nachos` directory.

Answer (score 0):

I have limited experience with Make, but what I would start to experiment with are the builders functionality in Eclipse.

Right click on a Project, select `properties`. In the new dialog, select `Builders`. Then create a new builder which is a program. Now you can tell it to run any external program and you can setup working directory, arguments, etc.

In the tab `Build options` you can set the new builder to run after Clean.

(On a separate note; check with the school if the Makefile is a requirement to use, or just intended as a "help", because it seems to rely on a non-standard Java setup and generally confuse things)

Comment: Yes, that's how I setup the builder to use make. It works perfectly fine. After compiling, the directory structure is as above. I setup a run configuration, and under "(x) = Arguments" I set the working directory to be in `nachos/proj1` and the run command to be `nachos.package1.Main`. However, Eclipse ignores this for some reason and "cannot find `nachos.package1.Main`". Is this a bug with Eclipse or am I misunderstanding the working directory of a run configuration.